# Python console: Error processing when file is saved however with a temporary output there is no problem

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-python-console

I am trying to execute a very simple raster calculator code in the python console:

```
processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:rastercalculator",{'EXPRESSION':'\"Sentinel2_Image2_NDVI@1\">0.09','LAYERS':['Sentinel2_Image2_NDVI'],'CELLSIZE':0,'EXTENT':None,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'Downloads/Sentinel2_Image2_NDVI_threshold.tif'})
```

However, the code just does not run. If I save the output to a temporary output there is no problem. I have tried saving in different directories and I computed it manually (saving to a directory) to which I get the following error message: **warning::1: resourcewarning: unclosed file**

To run this line of script I have the file open in QGIS.

It is also worth noting that I ran this line with Landsat data and it worked.

Comment: You probably opened `Sentinel2_Image2_NDVI_threshold.tif` file by another application(or a script) and forgot to close the file. Do you get the same error when using a random file name?

Comment: This file does not exist yet and when I give the output a different name, I still have the same problem

Comment: Did you try to specify a full path like `c:/foo/bar/output.tif`?

Comment: Yes, numerous different paths I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question resolved: As I was working with external drives, the errors appeared. Once I ran the code within a local directory it worked.